# Jquery css left change of image depending on div width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json

I have input which is dynamic from a JSON feed which populates a div with various names which are different in lengths.

There is an image which has been set to an absolute position which cannot be changed. Although I need to dynamically change the CSS left value of the image to whatever the width of the dynamic text that comes in `+ 10px`.

```
var _origin_width = $('#dynamic_text').width() + $('#the_imae').width();
```

So they are side by side like so

```
Dynamic Text | Image
```

I'm having trouble getting this to work.

Comment: variable not must be start with underscore(_) . :)

Comment: yeah i changed that, but still it didnt really do much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//get the width of content +10 in px
var dynamic_width = $('#dynamic_text').width()+10+'px';
//now set the css
$('#the_imae').css('left',dynamic_width)
```

Comment: yeah thanks allot I didn't know where i went wrong. its not exactly doing what i want but it is changing its position which it wasn't before. so you have been a great help. 

thank you very mu8ch